# Can you solve this circular dependency problem in C++?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, header, dependencies

There is an Object class with a clone() function that can throw a CloneNotSupportedException* and is declared such. CloneNotSupportedException derives from Exception, which derives from Object.

Inheritance requires complete types, and we have two of them, so it's obvious we can't break the circular dependency there. Member pointers and pointer parameters are content with incomplete types, but this is seemingly not enough for throw declarations, even if we throw pointers.

Class definitions are separate from implementations, forward declarations are used, pointers everywhere. This is still not enough.

Is there any way to break this dependency, or is this impossible in C++?

Comment: Repeat after me. "C++ is not Java". "C++ is not C# either". "C++ is not Java". "I really mean it, C++ is not Java". C++ does not have a common base class, *and that is a good thing*. It has proper copy constructors, so you don't need to muck around with clone functions, and it doesn't *need* huge inheritance hierarchies. And, of course, you should hardly ever be using pointers (or dynamically allocated objects) in C++. Please, buy a *good* C++ textbook, and try to learn the language, rather than writing Java in a .cpp file.

Comment: How could you usefully throw a pointer? Do yourself a favour, let your exception classes derive from `std::exception` and catch by const-reference.

Comment: The main circularity I have encountered with exceptions in C++, is that when you define string carrier class for exception message (so that constructing an exception object can't throw, as opposed to silly standard library design), then some operations of the string carrier class may need to throw exceptions... I have not found any satisfactory answer to that. There are workarounds, but they feel very construed, very artificial, ungood.

Comment: @jalf A lot of Bjarne Stroustrup's often repeated quotes glorify C++'s flexibility and multi-paradigm nature, that it does not force users into an arbitrary coding style. I have the freedom to choose my own, and I live with it. I value OOP design, dynamic polymorphism and proper inheritance hierarchies, and I code so. There is nothing wrong about it, unlike some of the features you seem to prefer. Copy constructors and assignment operators, while perfect for value types, are sources of potential danger, silent errors on polymorphic types, especially autogenerated ones forcing value semantics.

Comment: Ever heard of object slicing? Clone functions do not have that problem. Ill-defined inheritance hierarchies are not a good thing, it means the programmer is incapable of proper abstraction. That part about not using pointers and dynamically allocated objects is pure garbage. Any time you need dynamic, customizable behaviour, you use dynamic allocation, not cute tricks with value types. And those are a lot of cases. How would you ever implement a factory method without them? A simple observer pattern? Any kind of OOP solution? And kind of sensible code? And you haven't answered my question.

Comment: @Frigo: You completely can choose your own and I would never take away the language's ability to do that. That doesn't mean that it's not possible to do much better. OOP is not the solution to every problem- generic and functional programming offer vastly superior solutions in many cases- for example, the C++ Standard library's containers and algorithms. In C++, we don't have problems with object slicing because it's easily avoidable by not mixing value types and inheritance, we have smart pointers for that. Most ofthe time when you need dynamic, customizable behaviour- you use a container.

Comment: @Frigo: Oh, and in the C++ community, we usually regard patterns like factory and observer as crutches for languages that don't support the right paradigms to actually solve the problem, and they're rarely used in high-quality C++ code because we just don't need them. The observer pattern, for example, is just a hack around the fact that Java doesn't support functions as data, whereas in C++ we have function objects.

Comment: @Frigo: You have the freedom to do anything you like, including writing buggy, error-prone and fragile code. And including pretending that you're writing C, Java or Haskell. But if you pretend that this is **the right thing to do**, you're wrong.  I am merely pointing out that by all appearances, you are writing *terrible* code which is going to cripple your attempt at producing anything functional (never mind bug-free, or leak-free).

Comment: "That part about not using pointers and dynamically allocated objects is pure garbage" -- Uh, no. I'm sorry, but stubbornness does not a C++ guru make. Neither does ignorance, no matter how loud you shout it to the world. I've written quite a lot of sensible code in C++. And it didn't rely on idioms invented in Java to make up for *that* language's design flaws.

Comment: By the way, one little question. Why on Earth are you coding in C++? You're using styles and idioms which are just begging for subtle bugs, and which will cripple any hope you might have had of good performance. If you want to use this coding style, why not switch to a language designed for it, such as Java? You'll likely see *better* performance, and your code will become simpler and much more robust. C++ is, as you say, a multi-paradigm language, and that is its strength. As an OOP-only language, it *sucks*.

Comment: Why are you deriving `CloneNotSupportedException` from Object that seems silly to start with.  Why are you using exception specifications they have been depricated (and do not work the same way as Java anyway). Why are you creating a clone() method thats pointless and a sign of bad design. Looks like you are a Java developer tyrying to write C++ like Java. This is silly. Write the language like it is supposed to be written.

Comment: Come on guys, the question doesn't actually deserve downvoting.

Comment: @DeadMG
Of course, I use templates and STL, they are too valuable tools. / I know better than to mix polymorphic and value types, however, other people do not, and I had problems because of that. Since then, I derive all of my custom value types (with copy ctor and op=) privately from Final<T> to prevent any chance of object slicing. / I don't like smart pointers, there is a chance of cyclic dependencies in even innocent looking data structures. / Factory and observer isn't specific to Java, they arise naturally in certain problems. Function objects do not cover all cases.

Comment: @jalf
My code is not buggy, error-prone or fragile. It is more robust and stable than anything you have suggested so far. I have workarounds for common C++ errors and general stupidity of C++. I have almost all warnings switched on, bordering on the paranoid. I also have a garbage collector before you start spewing crap about leaks. And yes I am well aware that I am coding in C++, not Java, I am under no illusions to the contrary. I DO use C++ features not available in Java, like value types, operators or template metaprogramming, all where they make sense.

Comment: @jalf
There are several reasons I do not code in Java, like Oracle's attitude, no operator overloading, no proper templates, no custom value types, just to name a few. Performance wise, there are negligible losses due to GC and heap allocation. None if you use the proper kind of types in the proper context and code accordingly. Though I am still thinking about it, due to a few rabid fanboys of a subset of C++ smearing my coding style, not answering my question and in general being unconstructive.

Comment: @Martin 
I've just discovered this unsolvable cyclic dependency while playing around Object/Exception/CloneNotSupportedException, that's all. Clone is not a bad design if you don't want to deal with the difficulties of value types and the avalanche of const correctness.

Comment: @Frigo: Actually it is (Clone being a bad design (for C++)). But you seem to insist on fighting the whole C++ community in trying to change your mind. Feel free to keep writing C++ just like your Java. In the long run you will discover the error of your ways it will just be a long process were you discover exactly what has been already discovered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Skip the exception specification, it's worthless.

```
class Object {
    virtual Object* clone() = 0;
    virtual ~Object() {}
};
```

Done.

By the way, your design sounds so utterly wrong, I can't bring myself to not comment on it.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did, I see no other solutions.

Comment: Shouldn't the `clone` method be `const`?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <memory>
#ifndef NDEBUG
  #include <typeinfo>
#endif
#include <cassert>

class Object {
public:
  typedef std::unique_ptr<Object> Ptr;  // C++0x. Use auto_ptr in 03.

  virtual ~Object() { }

  Ptr clone() const {
    Ptr obj = cloneImpl();
    assert( typeid(*obj) == typeid(*this) );
    return obj;
  }

private:
  virtual Ptr cloneImpl() const = 0;
};
```

Just throw your exception by value and catch it by `const&`. If you `throw` your `CloneNotSupportedException` exception in `cloneImpl` it will propogate to the caller where they can handle it.

Comment: Instead of "Use `auto_ptr` in 03" I'd say "Use `boost::unique_ptr` in 03".

Answer (score -1):

I'm no C++ guru... but this is one (and only) case when I'd be tempted to throw something other than an Exception... you *could* throw a value type, such as an integer instead. I'm glad that the C++ language designers had the good sense to ban throwing pointers... that'd cause havoc.

Comment: They didn't. And no it wouldn't. In fact, stack allocated exceptions have problems with nested try...catch blocks and throws in destructors. Interfering with stack unwinding or something like that.

Comment: @Frigo: "or something like that"? Perhaps you could elaborate on that? Because apparently, none of the "normal" C++ authorities are aware of that problem, and uniformly suggest *not* throwing dynamically allocated exceptions. Perhaps you should inform Stroustrup of his mistake?